# Java GNU GetOpt: Understanding LongOpt's StringBuffer flag

Tags: java, getopt

I don't quite understand the purpose of the third constructor in [LongOpt](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnuprologjava/api/gnu/getopt/LongOpt.html). The [overview](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnuprologjava/api/gnu/getopt/Getopt.html) describes it as follows:

> If the flag field in the LongOpt object representing the long option is non-null, then the integer value field is stored there and an integer 0 is returned to the caller.

Excerpt from the above example to guide my observations/questions below:

```
 LongOpt[] longopts = new LongOpt[3];
 // 
 StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
 longopts[0] = new LongOpt("help", LongOpt.NO_ARGUMENT, null, 'h');
 longopts[1] = new LongOpt("outputdir", LongOpt.REQUIRED_ARGUMENT, sb, 'o'); 
 longopts[2] = new LongOpt("maximum", LongOpt.OPTIONAL_ARGUMENT, null, 2);
// ...
// See overview link above for full example
// ..
while ((c = g.getopt()) != -1)
  switch (c)
    case 0:
      arg = g.getOptarg();
      System.out.println("Got long option with value '" +
                     (char)(new Integer(sb.toString())).intValue()
                     + "' with argument " +
                     ((arg != null) ? arg : "null"));
      break;
      // ... Rest of example
```

So when looping through the options you'll get back 0. Of course that does not tell you which option we've hit so we put the "short form" of the long option, `o` for `--outputdir` above, into the StringBuilder object, `sb`. Extracting the char from that StringBuilder option allows you to see which long option it was and know what to do with the argument to that option.

Some questions:

- Is my understanding above correct?
- Why use a StringBuilder storing a char? Why not just have a regular string and put the full long option name, i.e. `outputdir` in that?
- Why not have the switch statement match on the long option string? I.e. `outputdir`. Is this because the library was written prior to JDK 7 when you could not switch on Strings? Then long options could be matched much like short options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I can provide some clarity to my own questions

> Is my understanding above correct?

I think it is based on experiments. But open to corrections for anyone who reads this in the future.

> Why use a StringBuilder storing a char? Why not just have a regular string and put the full long option name, i.e. outputdir in that?
>
> Why not have the switch statement match on the long option string? I.e. outputdir. Is this because the library was written prior to JDK 7 when you could not switch on Strings? Then long options could be matched much like short options.

Yes, the last commit to the only repo I can find is [8 years ago](https://github.com/arenn/java-getopt/commits/master). Hence the need to extract the matched option to a single `char` for use in the switch statement.

I have, instead, moved to using [Apache Commons CLI](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/) which has a much easier API